# Simple Mod rewrite working with 302 but not without

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a very simple mod rewrite section in my .htaccess file as below:

```
# Custom prime redirects
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule "^best-fixed-deposits" "/prime-deposits" [L,R=302]
# End Custom prime redirects
```

This works. But, if I remove the R=302, the server acts as if this rule is not there, throwing a 404 error.

I have this in the top of the .htaccess file.

Any clues?

thanks!

Comment: Without it, you would not be forcing an _external_ redirect any more. So your server would need to know how to handle `/prime-deposits` internally then, which presumably - it doesn’t.

Comment: Thanks, I figured it out by using Wordpress's add_redirect_rule function to do the redirs properly in WP context. The problem, as you pointed out, is to make sure that the server needs to know how to handle an internal redirect properly.